# GIS app with node+express+gdal+bigtiff

Tags: node.js, gis, mapbox, raster, gdal

I'm a newbie to the GIS world but after few weeks of hard searching/trying I feel stuck. 
I am building an app to analyse landcover to assess terrain roughness. All the logic will come later but now I try to design the architecture. 
A sample raster image is under the link:
[Africa landcover 20m resolution - small sample](https://towr.co/2F6svsi)

[a visualization of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8cvl.png)

**Goal:**
 - read raster file (BigTIFF/GeoTIFF, ...around 6GB) from a cloud storage, like AWS S3
 - use a javascript library to process the file, like node-gdal, geotiff.js, etc.
 - apply a vector polygon to the raster and count the different pixels within the polygon. THis will be a "circle" with a radius of 3km for instance. Also make some histograms, so to see which pixels are dominant within a quadrant or 1/8 of the area.
 - do some maths in JS with the data (about this I have no concerns)
 - visualize the raster image on a map including the vector polygon
 - push the code to production for multi users.

My skillset and limited experience is with the following as also my preferences to solve the challange:

- Node + Express (Javascript)
- Node-gdal library
- PostgreSQL
- Heroku for production
- [MApbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) for visulaizing the maps

***So far I have got the following issues when finding the right architecture or functioning codes:***

- [node-gdal](http://naturalatlas.github.io/node-gdal/classes/gdal.html) library can read only from the file system
- [geotiff.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geotiff) can do the job but less documentation and I cannot see how to handle the specific tasks later
- [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/features/) should be very powerfull but a bit cumbersome to setup. Furthermore I am not sure if it is worth for a single tiff raster to
  be feeded
- [Rasterio](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/) in Python can do very nice jobs and I managed in a Jupyter Notebook but I have no experience with Flask or others. Prefer Node JS
- [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) can do a lot but more for vectors, I could not find modules for raster analysis

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: So you are only going to read the raster once and then publish the results to the web?Will the 6km polygon/circle be fixed or user defined?  What server platform are you thinking for displaying the final raster to the end user?

Comment: @CorySilva Thanks your questions. ...Correct, I want to read the rasters once from that area, store the data in a DB and publish the result to the user, so not fixed. The polygon/circle will be dynamic, based on user input. Even, it shall be read from a CSV or something uploaded by the user, so reading from multiple locations. About the displaying server platform I was thinking about Mapbox. But I read about [plotty](https://github.com/santilland/plotty) (not Plotly) which is a small library working together with [geotiff.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geotiff) (the guys at Cesium)